# Have boost effect on lucene/compass field search

Tags: search, boost, lucene, compass-lucene

In our compass mapping, we're boosting "better" documents to push them up in the list of search results. Something like this:

```
<boost name="boostFactor" default="1.0"/>
<property name="name"><meta-data>name</meta-data></property>
```

While this works fine for fulltext search, it does not when doing a field search, e.g. the boost is ignored when searching something like

```
name:Peter
```

Is there any way to enable boosting for field searches?
Thanks for your help and sorry if this is a dumb question - I am new to Lucene/Compass.

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, please ignore this question. The reason was completely different, the search result got blurred by a bad query :(